# htaccess not working properly in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know there are many questions regarding this in stack overflow and many other sites. But I am unable to configure it properly. So I am posting the question here again. I have a server and has a many domains in it. I wrote a htaccess file to prevent .php at the end, but that is working for all the directories. I want it to work only in a specific domain.

For eg: Let's suppose I have two directories in /var/www/html/. One is proj1/ and other is proj2/. I want to write the rewrite rules only for proj2/ not for proj1/. If I place the htaccess file in /var/www/html/ all the directories in the directory is getting the rules. If I place htaccess file in proj1/ directory it is making some falsy redirects. So, how to make htaccess run it's rules only for proj1/ directory. My htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

I even tried changing rewritebase but it's not functioning properly. Thanks

For suppose if I keep this htaccess file in proj1/ directory and call any page such as localhost/proj1/login it redirects me to localhost/login (which actually doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteBase` rarely works the way you want it to. It's best to not use it:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /proj1/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /proj1/$1.php [NC,END]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that has no effect on redirects

Comment: @SandeshGhanta Does `RewriteBase /` work? If not, you should probably just not use `RewriteBase`. It doesn't always work the way you want it to. I'll update the answer when you respond

Comment: Thanks, Yes it did not work. I placed it in proj1/ and updated the rewritebase but not effect.

Comment: @SandeshGhanta The new answer should work. `RewriteBase` has some issues that make it difficult to use.